# attaching python objects (dictionaries) to existing pickle file

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use pickle to store a few python objects into a file. I know that while adding new objects to an existing pickle file I can load the existing objects and concatenate the new one:

```
# l is a list of existing dictionaries stored in the file:
l = pickle.load(open('existing_file.p', 'rb'))
new_dict = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
l = l + [new_dict]
# overwriting old file with the new content
pickle.dump(open('existing_file.p', 'rw'), l)
```

I wanted to check if there is any better way of attaching an object like a dictionary to an existing pickled file without overwriting the whole content.
Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickle` knows the length of its serialized objects so you can just keep appending new pickled objects to the end of the list and read them one at a time later. After creating some pickled objects by appending to my pickle file,

```
>>> with open('test.pickle', 'ab') as out:
...     pickle.dump((1,2,3), out)
... 
>>> with open('test.pickle', 'ab') as out:
...     pickle.dump((4,5,6), out)
```

I can read them back until I get an EOFError to know I'm done

```
>>> my_objects = []
>>> try:
...     with open('test.pickle', 'rb') as infile:
...         while True:
...             my_objects.append(pickle.load(infile))
... except EOFError:
...     pass
... 
>>> my_objects
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```